# Помогите разобраться с proxy в JS

Tags: javascript

Почему-то после написания Set в validator, Get перестал рабоать и правильно передавать prop(

```js
const validator = {
    get:function(person,prop){
        console.log('Trying to access the property '+prop+' ...')
         if(person[prop]===undefined){
             return false
         }
         return person[prop];
    },
    set:function(person,prop,value){
        console.log('Setting value '+value+' to '+prop+' ')
    }
}
let person = new Proxy({}, validator);

    

person.age = 100;
// Setting value '100' to 'age'
console.log(person.age);
// Trying to access the property 'age'...
// 100
person.gender = "male";
// Setting value 'male' to 'gender'
person.age = 'young';
// Uncaught TypeError: The age is not an integer
person.age = 300;
// Uncaught RangeError: The age is invalid
```

Comment: Ну так вы в set ничего не делаете, так что никакое значение не присваивается.

Comment: Да,но каким образом он вообзе влияет на Get 
Добавил остаток кода для большего понимания

Comment: В вашем коде нет никаких `TypeError`. Приведите настоящий код

Comment: Если я в validator комментирую или удаляю Set function,то при выводе в консоль console.log(person.age); я получаю 100,а если оставлю то в консоль выводится undefined или false
Хотелось бы понять с чем это свзяно

Comment: Так я ещё раз повторю, ваша функция `set` ничего не сохраняет в `person`, так что `get`-у просто нечего доставать.

Comment: Я понял,спасибо)